# Complete person account fields in apex

Tags: apex, person-accounts

I'm trying to create a person account in apex, but I have a problem. The fields like firstName, lastName are completed OK but the fields like PersonMailingPostalCode or fields like XXXX__pc aren't completed.

I post a sample of my code:

```
....
Account personAcc = new Account();
personAcc.firstName = 'Person';
personAcc.lastName = 'Account';
personAcc.BillingPostalCode = '23445';
personAcc.PersonMailingPostalCode = '29544';
personAcc.Job__pc = 'Quality control';
personAcc.RecordTypeId = RT_PERSONACCOUNT_ID;
listPersonAccounts.add(personAcc);
insert listPersonAccounts;
....
```

I hope you can help me

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by not completed? are getting any error?

Comment: @salesforcesas no, i don't get any error, I mean that the value is not assigned to the field when the account is inserted